# eclipse filter subprojects in project explorer

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to filter subprojects of a given eclipse project (named `grpc` in this particular case) in project-explorer, but no luck and couldn't find anything on the web.
The below screenshot shows what I've already tried. the filter `grpc*` works, but it filters all projects with name starting with `grpc`, while I just want to filter subprojects of `grpc` project, so that they don't pollute my project list when I switch to flat view.

Thanks!

[image: project explorer filtering]

Comment: The filter is only given the resource name, not the full path, so it can't match subprojects like this.

Comment: @greg-449 does it mean that it's currently basically impossible?  :-(

Comment: I don't see a way to do this. Personally I always just use the Hierarchical presentation and never switch to Flat.

Comment: Not with _User filters_ and not with _Project > Properties: Resource > Resource Filters_. But you can use a [_Working Set_](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm) to show only specific projects.

Comment: @howlger yeah, but working sets are useful for showing only a given group, rather than filtering-out some group: I'd need to create awkward working-sets like everything-but-this-and-this or dozens of small ones, but I guess I don't have other choice  ;-]  Thanks!

Comment: @howlger hmm: ...or I could create a working-set named `current` and just keep editing it's definition: it's just 1 additional click after all ;-)  Thanks again!

Comment: Oomph provides [_Dynamic Working Sets_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Dynamic_Working_Sets) (in the preferences _Oomph > Dynamic Working Sets_) that support exclusion patterns.